# Error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, date-formatting, mysql-error-1241

Am trying to select the day and month part for a range of date of a date field in mysql and its given me this error"Operand should contain 1 column(s)".
tablename is personal
date field name is dob

```
"SELECT *
FROM personal
WHERE (EXTRACT(MONTH
               FROM dob),
       EXTRACT(DAY
               FROM dob)) BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'"
```

dob is date field and the $fromdate and $todate holds a date input from the screen like "2014-04-30" and "2014-06-30

Comment: what is the datatype of column `dob`? And whatis the format of `$fromdate` and `$todate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CONCAT` in order to merge day and month from your dob column and then compare using between clause

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  personal 
WHERE
CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dob),'-',EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob))
BETWEEN '$fromdate'   AND '$todate'
```

Or better to use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the month and day only but make sure you have standard date object stored in column, and the format you provide in  `DATE_FROMAT` must match with the format of your provided parameters

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  personal 
WHERE
DATE_FROMAT(dob,'%m-%d')
BETWEEN '$fromdate'   AND '$todate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `WHERE` clause you can compare multiple values but one each at a time.

In your statement `WHERE` is trying to use both `MONTH` and `DAY` as separate values comma separated but comparing with `$fromdate` and `$tdate`, which is not correct.

And hence is the error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

You may be looking for a solution like this:

If `$fromdate` and `$todate` are in the format of `mmdd`, then

```
SELECT * FROM personal
WHERE date_format( dob, '%m%d' ) 
      BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'
```

Comment: tried the your solution and am having this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dob, '%m-%d' )BETWEEN '04-01' AND '12-30'' at line 1"

Comment: Can you post entire sql statement string you tried?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dob, '%m-%d' )BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'";

Comment: Remove the extra `WHERE` from `... personal WHERE WHERE DATE_...`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs across this error (I fought with it for hours before realizing my mistake)

You will also get this error if you accidentally put the cols for a SELECT in parenthesis

So if you are in a hurry and cut and paste your field list and type...

```
INSERT INTO mytablename(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT (col1, col2, col3) FROM anothertable WHERE col4 = 1;

instead of 
INSERT INTO mytablename(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM anothertable WHERE col4 = 1;
```

it throws the Operand should contain 1 column(s) error.